# Queue implementation with list interface of generic type

Tags: java, list, generics, queue, type-inference

I am required to make a Queue Class that accepts a generic type T that will be contained in it.

As a container for T, I have to use a generic List. The specific implementation (like ArrayList or LinkedList) has to be specified when the constructor of Queue is called, as a parameter.

Right now I have implemented the class as `Queue<T>` and the constructor accepts a Class of some kind that extends `List<T>`.

This way I should be able to create a new instance of the list by using `getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance()`.

```java
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.List;

// FIFO QUEUE
public class Queue<T> {
    private List<T> list;

    public Queue(Class<? extends List<T>> aClass) throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException {
        list = aClass.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
    }

    public boolean put(T element) {
        return list.add(element);
    }

    public T get() {
        T result = null;
        if (list.size() > 0) {
            result = list.remove(0);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public boolean empty() {
        return list.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

I then try to create a new instance of Queue in the main:

```
ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
Queue<Integer> queue = new Queue<>(arrayList.getClass());
```

Currently I am using IntelliJ IDEA and I cannot compile the code.

I am getting an error (`Cannot infer arguments`) pointing on `new Queue<>`.

How should I correctly call the constructor while maintaining encapsulation?

Comment: Try removing the `<T>` from the `Class<...` declaration.

Comment: If I do that I get a warning: `Unchecked assignment: 'capture<? extends java.util.List>' to 'java.util.List<T>'`

Comment: And then add an `@Suppressed("unchecked")` above the constructor.  This is just a `warning`, and _you're_ providing the guarantee that the unchecked assignment is safe.  Provided someone doesn't pass in a `class` which _specifically_ implements some `List<X>` where `X` is _non_ abstract, this should be fine.